# Script/Code to add/modify user accounts in Metatrader Manager

Tags: trading, metatrader4

I've been working with MT4 client app during several years, until there, everything is ok.

Now i need to work with "Metatrader Manager"; i need to manage user accounts, thousands of them, so i need to program some code to do it since it's impossible for me to do all the work manually. I can use Java, mql4, some script... But i've been searching through webs and more webs and i can't find any way to do it.

It seems to me that there is no other way to do it but manually, but it's impossible, isn't it?

I would appreciate any help on this, because i can't find any solution, as i say, and i really need to automate it if i want to keep my mind and fingers healthy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It exists such Java API I was asking about, but at a good price...

Comment: I am looking the same script or application . Can you tell me where did you buy it ?
I would be appreciate for any information .

Answer (score 0):

They have a c++ api for such things. 
Do you have an account on their support page.
https://support.metaquotes.net/en/articles/32