# Script or Code to add/modify user accounts in Metatrader Manager

Tags: metatrader4, forex

I would like to ask same question as Alberto Martin asked before here
[Script/Code to add/modify user accounts in Metatrader Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540720/script-code-to-add-modify-user-accounts-in-metatrader-manager)

***I need to work with "Metatrader Manager"; i need to manage user accounts, thousands of them, so i need to program some code to do it since it's impossible for me to do all the work manually. I can use Java, mql4, some script... But i've been searching through webs and more webs and i can't find any way to do it.***

he found an aswer as I saw, if some one or Alberto himself could help to find the answer please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Like Alberto said, most of the solutions out there cost $$$. If you're willing to pay just google things like "mt4 for java" or "mt4 for c#"
If not, you'll need to wrap the manager dll in some sort of interop layer so you can access it in script and or java/c#